# Entity Framework + Generic Repository + Unit Of Work => Entity is already attached

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext, unit-of-work

I have a problem with these two methods of my Generic Repository. In my controller, I retrieve the current user with my Unit of Work (which calls a repository which is based on the generic repository)

```
 CurrentUser = UtilisateurBuilder.Build(UnitOfWork.UsersRepository.Recuperer(user=>user.MailAddress==WebSecurity.CurrentUserName).First());
```

The above code is executed in the constructor of my controller, so I always have access to the current user infos. In one of my actions I have a code that performs some updates :

```
  CurrentUser.Photo = NewPathToPhoto;
  UnitOfWork.UsersRepository.Update(CurrentUser);
```

But at this point I get the following error :

> Attaching an entity of type 'DAL.User' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.

When I debug I see that the dbSet still contains the entity that was retrieve in the constructor controller. So my question is how I can get read of it, and how this pattern is supposed to work since I'm likely to retrieve an object before updating it everytime a update will be required..

Here is the relevant code of my generic repository :

```
public ICollection<TDomain> Recuperer(Expression<Func<TObject, bool>> filter = null,
            Func<IQueryable<TObject>, IOrderedQueryable<TObject>> orderby = null)
        {
            IQueryable<TObject> query = dbSet;

            if (filter != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(filter);
            }


            List<TDomain> objects = new List<TDomain>();
            foreach (TObject o in query)
            {
                objects.Add(Mapper.Map<TObject, TDomain>(o));
            }

            return objects;
        }

    public void Update(TDomain entity)
    {
        TObject o = Mapper.Map<TDomain, TObject>(entity);
        dbSet.Attach(o);
        context.Entry(o).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
```

Thank you !

**Update :**

I forgot important definitions from the Generic Repository :

```
 this.context = contextInjected;
 dbSet = context.Set<TObject>();
```

Comment: Sounds like you have issues with the db context passed to repositories. I suspect you have a two different instances in these two repositories.

Comment: I defined the context in my class as follow :
private readonly MyContext context = new MyContext();
Now I have a doubt, is it possible that every time I write
Repo1 repo = new Repo1(context);
Repo2 repo2 = new Repo2(context);
A new context is actually created ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the quickest fix is changing the first line in `Recuperer` into

```
IQueryable<TObject> query = dbSet.AsNoTracking();
```

This will prevent the object(s) from being attached to the context.

A more basic solution would be to find the attached user form the `DbSet.Local` collection, copy the properties from `TDomain entity` into it so the change tracker will modify the entity state itself and an update query will only update the modified properties.

Comment: Thank you Gert, I'm going to try the first solution right now. However I'm a little confused when you say "copy the properties from TDomain entity" for the second solution: how am I supposed to do that since it's a generic property ? And I also believe that I can't really do that because if I put that in the Update method, how can I know if Recuperer has been called before (if the entity is already in DbSet.Local)

Comment: If the entity is not in the local collection you can attach the incoming entity. Copying the properties can be done in [several ways](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592677.aspx).